# Extending a rational entry matrix to an orthogonal matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis, number-theory, reference-request

Suppose $M \leq N$ are positive integers and let $r_1,\ldots,r_M$ represent the rows of an $M\times N$ matrix $A$ in which: (i) the rows of $A$ are orthogonal and having the same norm, (ii) the columns of $A$ all have equal norm, and (iii) the entries of $r_i$ are all rational numbers. My question is when is it possible to extend this to an orthogonal-like $N \times N$ matrix with rational entries? That is an $N \times N$ matrix $Q$ so that $QQ^{T} = c\cdot I$ for some constant $c$.

I'm looking for any references possible that might lead to the answer. It's an interesting question, which I think might not be too obvious and may even be unknown? Thanks!

Comment: If the columns have equal norm that is a perfect rational square, or can be written as the sum of 2 rational squares, it can be done.

Comment: Can you elaborate on that? I'd appreciate it!

Comment: [Witt's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Witt%27s%5Ftheorem) does the perfect square (i.e. norm 1) case.

Comment: Awesome, I'll look into it. I thought this might drastically relate to rational quadratic forms, but unfortunately my number theory is not so good.

Comment: See [here](http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~may/VIGRE/VIGRE2006/PAPERS/Lin.pdf) for a non-quadratic formulation writeup. Though, those ideas are underlying it.

Comment: That's really awesome! Thanks!!

Comment: Can I ask if you have a reference to the two rational squares case, or does it follow from the one rational square case?

Comment: It's similar. Instead of sending 1 vector to $Ne_1$, you want to send 2 vectors to $Ae_1 + Be_2$ and $Be_2 - A e_1$.

Comment: See related  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/261204/every-integer-vector-in-mathbb-rn-with-integer-length-is-part-of-an-orthogon where the complete question was answered by J.S.Hsia in 1978: Two theorems on integral matrices. Linear Multilinear Algebra 5, 257-264 (1978).