# lebesgue's identity

Tags: elementary-number-theory

In the Lebesgue's identity $$ a^2+b^2+c^2=d^2$$ where: $$a=m^2+n^2-p^2-q^2$$ $$b=2(mp+nq) $$ $$c=2(mq-np) $$ $$d=m^2+n^2+p^2+q^2 $$how can we write $(m,n,p,q)$ as a function of the integers $(a,b,c,d)$? I have been trying and failing. Please help.

Comment: I believe that you have exchanged the formula for $d$ and for $a$.

There seems to be no beautiful formula.

Comment: @Martin-Blas Pere Pinilla, this is not Legendre's identity.

Comment: @Andy, too fast reading, sorry. Rolled back.

Comment: No problems.I understand.It happens to the best of us.

Comment: Not sure who first wrote this; do not see how you can solve your thing, or why you would want to; still, it is based on quaternion multiplication, see pdf at http://zakuski.math.utsa.edu/~kap/Forms/Pall_Automorphs_1940.pdf   and related articles at http://zakuski.math.utsa.edu/~kap/forms.html

Comment: see also my answer at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/660143/parametric-solution-for-the-sum-of-three-square

Comment: Solving the [linear] relations in $b$ and $c$ for $m$ and $n$ yields
$$
   (m,n) = \biggl(\frac{bp+cq}{2(p^2+q^2)},\ \frac{bq-cp}{2(p^2+q^2)} \biggr).
$$
Now by substitution,
$$
a = \frac{b^2+c^2-4(p^2+q^2)^2}{4(p^2+q^2)},
$$
and a similar fraction for $b$. From there, perhaps you can manipulate to get the function you need?

Comment: Perhaps even better would be to determine all of the two-square sums, _e.g._,
\begin{align}
d+a &= (m+n)^2 + (m-n)^2,  \\
d-a &= (p+q)^2 + (p-q)^2,  \\
d+b &= (m+p)^2 + (n+q)^2,  \\
d-b &= (m-p)^2 + (n-q)^2,  \\
d+c &= (m+q)^2 + (n-p)^2,  \\
d-c &= (m-q)^2 + (n+p)^2,
\end{align}
and then use those to work out the functions.

Comment: It's a beast. Thanks for your input.

Comment: links above are dead, but the base website is still visible at  http://zakuski.math.utsa.edu/~kap/

Answer (score 3):

*Lebesgue's Identity* is complete only if you add a ***scaling factor*** *t*. Hence,

$$\begin{align}
a &= (m^2+n^2-p^2-q^2)t\\
b &= 2(mp+nq)t\\
c &= 2(mq-np)t\\
d &= (m^2+n^2+p^2+q^2)t
\end{align}\tag{1}$$

As a function of the integers $a,b,c,d$, then the variables $m,n,p,q,t$ are simply,

$$\begin{align}
m &= \frac{-b-c}{a-d}\\
n &= \frac{-b+c}{a-d}\\
p &= 1\\
q &= 1\\
t &= \tfrac{1}{4}(-a+d)
\end{align}$$

If you substitute these into the eqns in $(1)$, for example,

$$(m^2+n^2-p^2-q^2)t-a = 0$$

then factor it, you get this [result](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Factor%5B%28%28%28-b-c%29%2F%28a-d%29%29%5E2%2B%28%28-b%2Bc%29%2F%28a-d%29%29%5E2-1%5E2-1%5E2%29%281%2F4%28-a%2Bd%29%29-a%5D), hence is true if indeed $a^2+b^2+c^2 = d^2$. (Similarly for the [2nd](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Factor%5B2%28%28%28-b-c%29%2F%28a-d%29%29%281%29%2B%28%28-b%2Bc%29%2F%28a-d%29%29%281%29%29%281%2F4%29%28-a%2Bd%29-b%5D), [3rd](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Factor%5B2%28%28%28-b-c%29%2F%28a-d%29%29%281%29-%28%28-b%2Bc%29%2F%28a-d%29%29%281%29%29%281%2F4%29%28-a%2Bd%29-c%5D), [4th](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=-Factor%5B%28%28%28-b-c%29%2F%28a-d%29%29%5E2%2B%28%28-b%2Bc%29%2F%28a-d%29%29%5E2%2B1%5E2%2B1%5E2%29%281%2F4%28-a%2Bd%29%29-d%5D) eqns.)

For the smallest solution,

$$1^2+2^2+2^2 = 3^2$$

we get $m,n,p,q,t = 2, 0, 1, 1,\tfrac{1}{2}$. And so on.

Comment: Piezas, I was not expecting $p=q=1$. It looks more like a particular case.

Comment: It is the general case. You can test it by substituting $m,n,p,q,t$ into the four eqns of $(1)$. (I've done the first for you in _WolframAlpha_.) Two will be identically true, while the other two are so if $a^2+b^2+c^2 = d^2$.

Comment: Actually, $p,q$ are **free** variables (as long as there is no division by zero). To make the formulas more aesthetic, I decided to set $p=q=1$ without loss of generality.

Comment: If you like this kind of number theory, then you have to invest in _Mathematica_ or _Maple_. Algebraic manipulation can be tedious without software, and life is short. :)

Comment: great idea :) I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

I may not understand the above answer but, it seems like there might not be an easy function to get all the possible values. Let's consider a simpler question:

In Euclid's identity $$ a^2+b^2=c^2$$ where: $$a=m^2-n^2$$ $$b=2mn $$ $$c=m^2+n^2 $$ how can we write $(m,n)$ as a function of the integers $(a,b,c)$?

If we are given any $a,b,c$ then we have basically been given a Pythagorean triple, the length of two legs and Hypoteneuse of a Pythagorean triangle. Let's consider the smallest such triangle, $a=3,b=4,c=5$. To find m and n, you basically need to find all $m,n$ so that the equations work. However, the equations will work for multiple $m,n$.

$$\begin{array} { | r r | c | c | c | c |  c |  c  | }
 & & & & & a= & b= & c= \\
m & n & m^2 & 2mn & n^2 & m^2-n^2 & 2mn & m^2+n^2 \\
-2 & -1 & 4 & 4 & 1 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
2 & 1 & 4 & 4 & 1 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
\end{array}$$

It appears to me that the original question is asking a similar question about Pythagorean Quadruples, and it seems like there will be a huge increase in possible values for $m,n,p,q$ since there are more opportunities for postives and negatives to create the same values in the final $a,b,c,d$. For example, consider if we are given $a=245,b=10,c=70,d=255$

$$\begin{array} { l }
a=245=m^2+n^2-p^2-q^2 \\
b=10=2(mp+nq)\\
c=70=2(mq-np)\\
d=255=m^2+n^2+p^2+q^2\\
a^2+b^2+c^2=d^2\\
245^2+10^2+70^2=255^2=65025\\
\end{array}$$

It appears there are at least 8 sets of valid values for m,n,p,q, found using a simple python program that just ran through all possible values of m,n,p,q between -16 and 16:

$$\begin{array} { | r r r r | c | c | r r | r r | }
m & n & p & q & m^2+n^2 & p^2+q^2 & mp & nq & mq & np \\
-15 & 5 & -1 & -2 & 250 & 5 & 15 & -10 & 30 & -5 \\
-13 & -9 & 1 & -2 & 250 & 5 & -13 & 18 & 26 & -9 \\
-9 & 13 & -2 & -1 & 250 & 5 & 18 & -13 & 9 & -26 \\
-5 & -15 & 2 & -1 & 250 & 5 & -10 & 15 & 5 & -30 \\
5 & 15 & -2 & 1 & 250 & 5 & -10 & 15 & 5 & -30 \\
9 & -13 & 2 & 1 & 250 & 5 & 18 & -13 & 9 & -26 \\
13 & 9 & -1 & 2 & 250 & 5 & -13 & 18 & 26 & -9 \\
15 & -5 & 1 & 2 & 250 & 5 & 15 & -10 & 30 & -5 \\
\end{array}$$

Notice that $250=m^2+n^2$ is built from $13^2+9^2$ becoming $169+81$, but also $15^2+5^2$ becoming $225+25$. Then $p^2+q^2$ is always $5$, which is added or subtracted to created $a=245$ or $d=255$. Similar things happen with the terms for $b$, which always becomes $2*5=10$ and $c$, which always becomes $2*35=70$

This link seems somewhat relevant: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/29644/enumerating-ways-to-decompose-an-integer-into-the-sum-of-two-squares